# SI Kafka producer consumer running in the same spring application context issue

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am loading the kafka consumer configuration at application start up and then  running the kafka producer to produce the messages getting below error(both producer and consumer are running in the same application context which is the requirement).

any suggestion on this?

```
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">
<int-kafka:producer-configurations>
    <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
               key-class-type="java.lang.String"
               value-class-type="com.test.MessageVo"
               topic="inMessage_topic"
               value-encoder="valueEncoder"
               key-encoder="keyEncoder"
               compression-type="none"/>
 </int-kafka:producer-context>

<bean id="valueEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
   <constructor-arg value="com.test.MessageVo" />
</bean>

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext" consumer-timeout="4000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
   <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
       <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="default"
               value-decoder="valueDecoder"
               key-decoder="keyDecoder"
               max-messages="5000">
           <int-kafka:topic id="inMessage_topic" streams="4"/>
       </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
```

log:

```
  creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@22981654]
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter'
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
18:31:03.139 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase -2147483648
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.GlobalChannelInterceptorProcessor]
18:31:03.139 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.c.GlobalChannelInterceptorProcessor - No global channel interceptors.
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 0
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean]
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@27ff9f78.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 1073741823
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean]
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - started kafkaInboundChannelAdapter
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter'
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean]
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
18:31:03.140 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
18:31:03.140 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter'
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
18:31:03.142 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
18:31:03.143 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase -2147483648
18:31:03.143 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.GlobalChannelInterceptorProcessor]
18:31:03.143 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
18:31:03.143 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 0
18:31:03.143 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' of type [class org.springframework.integration.channel.DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry]
18:31:03.144 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
18:31:03.144 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 1073741823
18:31:03.144 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
18:31:03.144 [task-scheduler-3-SendThread(192.168.4.102:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.4.102/192.168.4.102:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
18:31:03.145 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
18:31:03.145 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
18:31:03.145 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
18:31:03.145 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[MergedContextConfiguration@588b873e testClass = NotificationServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:/bootstrap-test.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
18:31:03.149 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'com.notificationengine.NotificationServiceTest': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.notificationengine.service.NotificationService com.notificationengine.NotificationServiceTest.notificationService
18:31:03.150 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'notificationService'
18:31:03.150 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'com.notificationengine.NotificationServiceTest' to bean named 'notificationService'
18:31:03.154 [task-scheduler-2] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.4.102:2181 sessionTimeout=400 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@2351449c
18:31:03.155 [task-scheduler-2-SendThread(192.168.4.102:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.4.102/192.168.4.102:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
Started.testNotify
g reply sessionid:0x14fdaa20a9400b7, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 2,5  replyHeader:: 2,24649,0  request:: '/config/topics/inMessage_topic,#7b2276657273696f6e223a312c22636f6e666967223a7b7d7d,-1  response:: s{22809,24649,1442483209580,1442494932319,14,0,0,0,25,0,22809}
18:31:03.381 [task-scheduler-3-SendThread(192.168.4.102:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x14fdaa20a9400b5, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 2,3  replyHeader:: 2,24649,0  request:: '/consumers/test-consumer-group/ids,T  response:: s{9182,9182,1441255409611,1441255409611,0,2250,0,0,0,4,24648}
18:31:04.058 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel - preSend on channel 'inputToKafka', message: GenericMessage [payload=InMessageVO [notificationMethodTypes=[EMAIL], contentReferenceCode=Booking_Confirmataion, moduleName=notification, tenantId=KF, notificationTypeToRecieverMap={EMAIL={TO_ADDRESS=[ne.test@test.com]}}, notificationTypeToMessageDetailsMap={EMAIL={EMAIL_CONTENT=Hi <BR> This is a test email from  NE <BR> Regards<BR>-NE, EMAIL_SUBJ=Test Message from NE}}], headers={timestamp=1442494864039, id=0c14746e-93b4-ced0-2fc2-e7117fef3409, tenantId=base, kafka_messageKey=key, kafka_partitionId=3, kafka_topic=inMessage_topic}]
18:31:04.058 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inputToKafka', message: GenericMessage [payload=InMessageVO [notificationMethodTypes=[EMAIL], contentReferenceCode=Booking_Confirmataion, moduleName=notification, tenantId=KF, notificationTypeToRecieverMap={EMAIL={TO_ADDRESS=[ne.test@test.com]}}, notificationTypeToMessageDetailsMap={EMAIL={EMAIL_CONTENT=Hi <BR> This is a test email from  NE <BR> Regards<BR>-NE, EMAIL_SUBJ=Test Message from NE}}], headers={timestamp=1442494864039, id=0c14746e-93b4-ced0-2fc2-e7117fef3409, tenantId=base, kafka_messageKey=key, kafka_partitionId=3, kafka_topic=inMessage_topic}]
18:31:05.014 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Init connection to node -1 for sending metadata request in the next iteration
18:31:05.014 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at tncdev6.com:9092.
18:31:05.017 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
18:31:05.049 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node -1
18:31:05.117 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
18:31:05.129 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Sending metadata request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, payload=null, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=3,api_version=0,correlation_id=0,client_id=producer-1}, body={topics=[inMessage_topic]})) to node -1
18:31:05.177 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(0, 192.168.4.102, 9092)], partitions = [Partition(topic = inMessage_topic, partition = 1, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,], Partition(topic = inMessage_topic, partition = 4, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,], Partition(topic = inMessage_topic, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,], Partition(topic = inMessage_topic, partition = 2, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,], Partition(topic = inMessage_topic, partition = 3, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,]])
18:31:05.213 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
18:31:05.215 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node 0 at 192.168.4.102:9092.
18:31:09.041 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@3de0a45 testClass = NotificationServiceTest, testInstance = com.notificationengine.NotificationServiceTest@667439fe, testMethod = testNotify@NotificationServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@588b873e testClass = NotificationServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:/bootstrap-test.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
18:31:09.043 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@3de0a45 testClass = NotificationServiceTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@588b873e testClass = NotificationServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:/bootstrap-test.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
18:31:09.045 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@551eef55: startup date [Thu Sep 17 18:31:01 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
18:31:09.046 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
18:31:09.047 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
18:31:09.047 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
18:31:09.047 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaProducerContext'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
18:31:09.048 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
18:31:09.049 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 1073741823
18:31:09.049 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.050 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.050 [task-scheduler-9] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
18:31:09.050 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
18:31:09.050 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.050 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.050 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
18:31:09.050 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
18:31:09.050 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - stopped kafkaInboundChannelAdapter
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2
18:31:09.051 [task-scheduler-8] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
18:31:09.051 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.051 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - stopped kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter
18:31:09.051 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.052 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.052 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
18:31:09.052 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4
18:31:09.052 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Consuming from Kafka failed; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException, headers={timestamp=1442494869052, id=f339b359-27d3-03e8-2cce-e80c31970c55}]
18:31:09.052 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 0
18:31:09.052 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - (inner bean)#78f92fba received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Consuming from Kafka failed; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException, headers={timestamp=1442494869052, id=f339b359-27d3-03e8-2cce-e80c31970c55}]
18:31:09.052 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'kafkaProducerContext' of type [class org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext] to stop
18:31:09.052 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Sender - Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
18:31:09.053 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Sender - Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - The Kafka producer has closed.
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'kafkaProducerContext' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@551eef55.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' completed its stop procedure
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase -2147483648
18:31:09.054 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4ed405e2: defining beans [loadConsumer,kafkaProducer,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,notificationService,emailNotificationDispatchService,notificationReceiverMessageHandler,emailNotificationReceiverMessageHandler,channelInitializer,$autoCreateChannelCandidates,IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor,integrationEvaluationContext,org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,integrationGlobalProperties,integrationHeaderChannelRegistry,globalChannelInterceptorProcessor,toStringFriendlyJsonNodeToStringConverter,converterRegistrar,integrationConversionService,DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,datatypeChannelMessageConverter,messageBuilderFactory,inMessage_topic,org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,fixedSubscriberChannelBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0,org.springframework.integration.context.defaultPollerMetadata,inputFromKafka,receiveMessageFromKafkaChannel,kafkaKeyDecoder,kafkaValueDecoder,kafkaInboundChannelAdapter.source,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#1,kafkaInboundChannelAdapter,consumerContext,consumerProperties,conditionalConsumerService,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2,zookeeperConnect,sendMessageToKafkaChannel,inputToKafka,conditionalProducerService,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#2,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3,org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#2,kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter,kafkaProducerContext,producerProperties,kafkaKeyEncoder,kafkaValueEncoder,taskExecutor,kafkaProducerService,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#3,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4,org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#1,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#3,nullChannel,errorChannel,_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger,taskScheduler,org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0]; root of factory hierarchy
18:31:09.055 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#78f92fba': [_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger]
18:31:09.055 [task-scheduler-3] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Consuming from Kafka failed; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException
       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfiguration.executeTasks(ConsumerConfiguration.java:150)
       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfiguration.receive(ConsumerConfiguration.java:124)
       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaConsumerContext.receive(KafkaConsumerContext.java:73)
       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSource.receive(KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSource.java:41)
       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
```

Comment: continuation of log :

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is; that log is completely unreadable in that format; you need to format it, or post it someplace else. That said, there's a [pull request for a sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/pull/144) that has both a producer and consumer in the same context with no problems.

Comment: I've cleaned up your post a little, but to fit in the formatting I had to cut another line of log. Perhaps you need to figure out what information is redundant and reduce the log further to just the essentials (with perhaps a full log hosted in a GitHub gist or similar).

Comment: added the full log trace in the below location .thanks.https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67cd05703b09fad82d2a

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where is your error. Since you are in the it is normal that your context is closed in the end. So, that InterruptedException just says that some Ina-flight tasks are stopped by force.

Comment: Thanks @Artem,I was also thinking the same but was not sure.thanks.